# How to get Ubuntu installed on a flash drive that can be accessed in Windows?

Tags: installation, usb-drive, format

I have a flash drive that I am considering installing Ubuntu on. However, I would also like the contents to be accessible in Windows. Is this possible?

Some further details:

- I ruled out NTFS because (IIRC) it can't be mounted as `/`.
- It needs to be formatted with a filesystem that Windows will recognize without any IFS drivers or utilities that require admin privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ***always*** format my thumbdrive as FAT32 (since it's only a 4GB, as well as for the same reasons that you posted), and I install Ubuntu liveCDs on that partition. So, I would say that FAT32 would be your best bet. It's what I personally use, and I've never encountered any problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

USB flash drives are virtually always formatted with FAT32.  When you install Ubuntu to it using the liveUSB creator, its root filesystem is placed in a loopback file within the FAT32 fs.